# box.removeAll and subscriptions

Tags: objectbox

Just can't find any additional info in docs, but I wondered why this subscription is not going to work when I call `box.removeAll()` for the android implementation of lib? Is it expected behavior?

```
    val observer: DataSubscription = subscribe()
        .onError { error: Throwable? -> close(error) }
        .observer { data: List<T> -> offer(data) }
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to reproduce this, but after `box.removeAll()` the observer correctly gets an empty list. If you have a test case to reproduce this, can you please submit details to https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues? Uwe

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's kinda a mistake in stubbing which leads me to this conclusion. Anyway, thank you for your answer!